# Get rid of BitTorrent Bundle

Tags: bittorrent

This is getting very annoying! Whenever I open BitTorrent, I don't see my downloads. It just shows me this BitTorrent Bundle thingy.

How do I get rid of this so that I can resume my downloads?

[image]

Comment: A screenshot would be helpful.  You calling it a "thingy" isn't descriptive enough.

Comment: I don't know how I got this. :(

Comment: [What is BitTorrent Bundle](http://www.zeropaid.com/news/104031/what-is-bittorrent-bundle/), "The BitTorrent Bundle is not an album, an MP3, or an MOV. It’s a multimedia format. It’s an early build of a new type of torrent file where fan interaction, like email collection or donation, happens inside the torrent."

Comment: [Updated From 7.6.1 To 7.9.1 & I Get This Bittorrent Bundle Screen Not An App](http://forum.bittorrent.com/topic/29420-updated-from-761-to-791-i-get-this-bittorrent-bundle-screen-not-an-app/?hl=bundle)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to `Options` and verify that you have check mark on `show sidebar`. If you don't, check it and it will be shown on your left side:

- Bundles
- Torrents()
- Feeds()
- Devices()

Click on Torrents and you'll see torrents that you downloading and the ananoing Bundle screen will be gone.

Comment: The above answer tells you how to get there. A small further comment. You right click on "Bundles" name and it provides option to hide. That will solve the problem.